# memsql how to free space from plancachedir

Tags: singlestore

I have a very small memsql instance which have on 200 tables 200MB data in total.  The plancachedir kept fulling the file system (25GB+). I tried to shutdown the databases, deleted files under plancachedir. but after restarted database, all files came back. "show plancache" show 0 entries so there's no plans to be deleted.

Would anyone let me know the best way to manage the plancachedir space consumption?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So, if you are comfortable turning off your machine and deleting the plancache directory, try just running `SNAPSHOT <db_name>` on each database before turning off the server and deleting the plancache.
Otherwise the queries will be recompiled for every write query and alter table you ran during recovery.

25 Gigs is a lot though...

To be honest, MemSQL is not optimized for the case of many 1-meg tables...
Depending on your use case, it might be worth investigating our JSON datatype, or rethinking your schemas.

Comment: Its worth mentioning; each node has its own plancache.  If you are running cluster-in-a-blox, there will be at least two MemSQL installs in your installs dir, each with their own plancache.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. It's very helpful. I did snapshot for each of my databases and shutdown, deleted plancachedir, restarted database, however, the space did not release much. I noticed the space consumption was caused by number of tables - each new table consumed around 150MB right after its creation. So I guess it's just a feature of MemSQL that I should plan more space for.